# Finding maximum possible sum of numbers in arithmetic progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have a game where prices increment linearly depending on the amount you have, so if you have 0 widgets buying 1 costs \$5 and buying 2 costs \$15 (10 for the second), the $30 for 3 (15 for the third).

Suppose I have $10e20 and 700 widgets, how many more widgets can I buy?

In general, given a starting amount of widgets $w$ and money $m$, is there a way to calculate $n$ (that doesn't involve trial and error) where

$$\sum_{i=w+1}^{w+n} 5i \leq m ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=w+1}^{w+n} 5i \leq m$$
$$5\sum_{i=w+1}^{w+n} i \leq m$$
$$5\left(\sum_{i=1}^{w+n} i -\sum_{i=1}^{w} i\right)\leq m$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{w+n} i -\sum_{i=1}^{w} i\leq \frac{m}{5}$$
$$\frac{\left(w+n\right)^2+w+n}{2} -\frac{w^2+w}{2}\leq \frac{m}{5}$$
$$\frac{w^2+2wn+n^2+w+n-w^2-w}{2}\leq \frac{m}{5}$$
$$\frac{n^2+2wn+n}{2}\leq \frac{m}{5}$$
$$n^2+2wn+n\leq \frac{2m}{5}$$
$$n^2+n(2w+1)\leq \frac{2m}{5}$$
$$n^2+n(2w+1)+\frac{4w^2+4w+1}{4}\leq \frac{2m}{5}+\frac{4w^2+4w+1}{4}$$
$$\left(n+\frac{2w+1}{2}\right)^2\leq \frac{2m}{5}+\frac{4w^2+4w+1}{4}$$
$$n+\frac{2w+1}{2}\leq \sqrt{\frac{2m}{5}+\frac{4w^2+4w+1}{4}}$$
$$n\leq \sqrt{\frac{2m}{5}+\frac{4w^2+4w+1}{4}}-\frac{2w+1}{2}$$
$$n=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{2m}{5}+\frac{4w^2+4w+1}{4}}-\frac{2w+1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 0):

A useful result to know for such problems is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$
In your case, e.g.
$$
\begin{split}
25 + 30 + 35 + \ldots + 200
 &= \sum_{i=5}^{40} 5i \\
 &= 5 \sum_{i=5}^{40} i \\
 &= 5\left(\sum_{i=1}^{40} i - \sum_{i=1}^{4} i\right) \\
 &= 5 \left( \frac{40 \cdot 41}{2} - \frac{4 \cdot 5}{2}\right)
\end{split}
$$

---

A different way to see that is to subtract 25 from every sum getting
$$
25 + \ldots 200 = 25 \cdot 36 + 5(1 + 2 + \ldots + 35)
 = 900 + 5 \times \frac{35 \cdot 36}{2}
$$
from the same formula above.